# interpret Scanner close( ) method Java

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

When I need to close a `Scanner` by method `close()`, I have a code as follows, could any one explain why I need to check `if(input != null`) please ?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("System.txt"));

...

Public void closeFile() {
   if(input != null) {
          input.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> could any one explain why I need to check if(input != null) please ?

its just a `null check` if input is null it'd throw **NullPointerException**.

consider below code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("System.txt"));
    public void someMethod(){
      input = doSomething(); //say doSomething() returns null
    }
    Public void closeFile()
   {
   if(input != null)
      input.close();
    }
```

now, as input is null, if you try to call close() it'd throw NPE>

Comment: right, input reads records from the text file, by input.hasNext(), so in this method, it will return null, thanks !

Comment: @Twocold not really Scanner.hasNext() return boolean not Scanner instance, what i meant was doSomething() which is supposed to return a Scanner instance could return null

Comment: one more question, if I could check the NPE in the someMethod() instead of the closeFile() method ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could `input` be set to null *elsewhere* ? I note that the assignment isn't `final` and as such it could be reassigned (given appropriate access rights)

Comment: the situation is i need to input a text file by scanner and read it, then close it at the end with the codes I provided above, so ... any thoughts plz ?